# ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, sql, database

```
    String sql="SELECT room_no, suite_type, bed_type, suite_cost FROM room_detail "    
             + "where room_no NOT IN "+
             + "(SELECT room_no FROM booking_table WHERE DATE(date_out) >= '" 
             + strdtver1 
             + "' AND DATE(date_in) <= '" 
             + strdtver2 
             + "')";
```

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Question tags completely changed -- your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with Swing, and so I've removed that tag (which was your *only* tag). Please take care with your question tags as they and your question title are the primary factors in attracting the right experts to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your variable `strdtver1` to date type before comparing it.

So, your query needs to be changed like the following:

```
 String sql="SELECT room_no, suite_type, bed_type, suite_cost FROM room_detail "    
+ "where room_no NOT IN "+
+ "(SELECT room_no FROM booking_table WHERE TO_DATE(date_out,'DD-MON-YY') >= to_date('" 
+ strdtver1 
+ "','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE(date_in,'DD-MON-YY') <= to_date('" 
+ strdtver2 
+ "','DD-MON-YY') )";
```

Also, you don't need semi-colon in your query string.